# ERROR: Unexpected output from "ps" command when running `rush update` with `node-safe`

Tags: macos, rush, microsoft-rush

I use [node-safe](https://github.com/berstend/node-safe) to run Node.js commands sanboxed on macOS. I also try to use Rush.js

When I run `rush update`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected output from "ps" command
```

The error doesn't happen when I run the command with `--allow-all` flag for `node-safe`, but this disabled sandbox completely. When I manually give every possible permission to the command (`(allow system*)` and others), I still get this error

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging, I've found [this comment](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/13727#issuecomment-892835795) in Bazel repository (they also happen to use macOS built-in sandboxing)

`rush update` uses `/bin/ps` to get the process start time (no idea why). The error originates from around [here](https://github.com/microsoft/rushstack/blob/3e975391ecb0f500508e29c3687eb5a3c077574c/libraries/node-core-library/src/LockFile.ts#L119) if you're interested

The comment explains that `/bin/ps` has to be run unsandboxed. To do that in the sandbox configuration file, you need to add `(allow process-exec (with no-sandbox) (literal "/bin/ps"))` to your sandbox file

There is currently no way to do that in `node-safe`. You can fork it and add this option, or use [my fork](https://github.com/azerum/node-safe/tree/feat-custom) to add this clause (see the top readme.md)

This could be done prettier, but it seems like an obscure use-case. If you had the same problem and this helped you, I will think about way of adding such feature into `node-safe` repo. Please comment to let me know in such case